# Pubnub Sending not equal to receiving?

Tags: android, python, pubnub

From my PI I send a message through pubnub that contains the sequince of Leds that have been burned. Weird enough I receive something different in my Android app.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
#
import random
import time
import sys
from time import sleep
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from pubnub import Pubnub


pubnub = Pubnub(publish_key='pub-c-da666f8d070cace', 
subscribe_key='sub-c-93dab7fe')

CHANNEL_IN = 'in'
CHANNEL_OUT = 'out'

def blink_leds():
    leds = [18,17,27,22]
    random.shuffle(leds)
    volgorde = ', '.join(str(led) for led in leds)
    GPIO.setwarnings(False)
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
    for led in leds:
        GPIO.setup( led, GPIO.OUT)
    for led in leds:
        for state in [True,False]:
            GPIO.output(led, state)
            sleep(0.5)
    return volgorde

def run():
    print("blinking leds")
    volgorde = blink_leds()
    print("sending code")
    print(volgorde)
    pubnub.publish(CHANNEL_IN,volgorde)

def stop():
    GPIO.cleanup()
    pubnub.unsubscribe(CHANNEL_OUT)
def callback(message,channel):
    if 'Inorde' in str(message):
        print("Inorde")
        run()
    if 'Fout' in str(message):
        print("Fout")
        stop()
    if 'Start' in str(message):
        print("starting")
        run()

pubnub.subscribe(channels=CHANNEL_OUT, callback=callback)
pubnub.publish(CHANNEL_IN,"Start")
```

What am i doing wrong?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FqCLk.png)

My activity: 
    package be.thomasmore.sequincepi;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.*;
import android.widget.AbsoluteLayout;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.pubnub.api.*;

import org.json.*;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Random;

public class play extends Activity {
    private Pubnub mPubNub;
    public static final String PUBLISH_KEY = "pub-c-da6362de-5562-43a7-9b0e-66f8d070cace";
    public static final String SUBSCRIBE_KEY = "sub-c-935fbdb2-df94-11e5-8905-02ee2ddab7fe";
    public static final String CHANNEL_IN = "in";
    public static final String CHANNEL_OUT = "out";
    Button btn1;
    Button btn2;
    Button btn3;
    Button btn4;
    TextView txtHaal;
    public String volgorde = "";
    public String antwoord = "";
    public int score = 0;
    TextView txtScore;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.play);
        btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        btn3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        btn4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
        txtHaal = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtHaal);
        txtScore = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtScore);
        initPubNub();
        knoppen();
    }

      private void knoppen() {
        btn1.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Button button = (Button) v;
                button.setEnabled(false);
                antwoord += "1";
                controleer();
            }
        });
        btn2.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Button button = (Button) v;
                button.setEnabled(false);
                antwoord += "2";
                controleer();
            }
        });
        btn3.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Button button = (Button) v;
                button.setEnabled(false);
                antwoord += "3";
                controleer();
            }
        });
        btn4.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Button button = (Button) v;
                button.setEnabled(false);
                antwoord += "4";
                controleer();
            }
        });
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                btn1.setEnabled(false);
                btn2.setEnabled(false);
                btn3.setEnabled(false);
                btn4.setEnabled(false);
            }
        });
    }


    public void controleer() {
        if (antwoord.length() == 4) {
            if (antwoord.equals(juisteNummers(volgorde))) {
                publish("Inorde");
                score++;
                String.valueOf(score);

            }else{
                txtHaal.setText("Fout");
                publish("Fout");
            }
        }
    }

    public void setTextView(final TextView textView, final String text) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                textView.setText(text);
            }
        });
    }

    public void initPubNub() {
        this.mPubNub = new Pubnub(
                PUBLISH_KEY,
                SUBSCRIBE_KEY);
        this.mPubNub.setUUID("SequencePI");
        subscribe();
    }

    public void subscribe() {
        try {
            this.mPubNub.subscribe(CHANNEL_IN, new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void connectCallback(String channel, Object message) {
                    Log.d("PUBNUB", "SUBSCRIBE : CONNECT on channel:" + channel
                            + " : " + message.getClass() + " : "
                            + message.toString());
                }

                @Override
                public void disconnectCallback(String channel, Object message) {
                    Log.d("PUBNUB", "SUBSCRIBE : DISCONNECT on channel:" + channel
                            + " : " + message.getClass() + " : "
                            + message.toString());
                }

                public void reconnectCallback(String channel, Object message) {
                    Log.d("PUBNUB", "SUBSCRIBE : RECONNECT on channel:" + channel
                            + " : " + message.getClass() + " : "
                            + message.toString());

                }

                @Override
                public void successCallback(String channel, Object message) {
                    Log.d("PUBNUB", "SUBSCRIBE : " + channel + " : "
                            + message.getClass() + " : " + message.toString());

                    //juisteNummers(message.toString());
                    if(message.toString().contains("Start")){
                        publish("Start");
                    }else{
                        volgorde = message.toString();
                        antwoord ="";
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                btn1.setEnabled(true);
                                btn2.setEnabled(true);
                                btn3.setEnabled(true);
                                btn4.setEnabled(true);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void errorCallback(String channel, PubnubError error) {
                    Log.d("PUBNUB", "SUBSCRIBE : ERROR on channel " + channel
                            + " : " + error.toString());
                }
            });

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public void publish(String done) {
        JSONObject js = new JSONObject();
        try {
            js.put(CHANNEL_OUT, done);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Callback callback = new Callback() {
            public void successCallback(String channel, Object response) {
                Log.d("PUBNUB", response.toString());
            }

            public void errorCallback(String channel, PubnubError error) {
                Log.d("PUBNUB", error.toString());
            }

        };
        this.mPubNub.publish(CHANNEL_OUT, js, callback);
    }

    public String juisteNummers(String volgorde) {
        String vol = "";
        HashMap<String,String> omzetting = new HashMap<>();
        omzetting.put("17","1");
        omzetting.put("18","2");
        omzetting.put("22","3");
        omzetting.put("27","4");
        for (int i = 0;i<=12;i+=4) {
            vol += omzetting.get(volgorde.substring(i, i + 2));
        }
        return vol;
    }


}
```

Comment: I just found out that he sends 4 different messages. Still dont know why

Comment: Hey Ynias, your publish and subscribe keys seem different in the python and Android code. Is it just a typo when pasting into Stack overflow? If not, make sure they are the same in both, else you won't be able to send and receive messages between the two devices.

Answer (score 0):

Your pub/sub keys in your Python code do not match the pub/sub keys in your Android code. And you shouldn't post your full keys in public.